# AngularJS custom form component / directive using ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-forms

### Angular custom form component / directive and $dirty property

When using regular input, such as

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="foobar">
</form>
```

after typing in the input box `myForm.$dirty` is true.

I'd like to create a simple directive such as

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      fooBar: '='
    },
    template: '<div><button ng-click="fooBar=foo"></button><button ng-click="fooBar=bar"></button></div>'
  };
});
```

Sample usage would be

```
<form name="myForm">
  <my-directive foo-bar="myObj.foobarValue"></my-directive>
</form>
```

and after user clicks on any of the two buttons, `myForm$dirty` is set to true.

How is this accomplished?

Comment: It would be easier if the directive was defined to act per button rather than any button in the template, would that be acceptable?

Comment: Use [ngFormController API - $setDirty](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setDirty)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)

Use the [ngModel controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) and the object form of the [`require` property](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) in the DDO:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: { ngModelCtrl: 'ngModel' },
    scope: {
      ngModel: '<'
    },
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    template: 
       `<div>
          <button ng-click="$ctrl.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue('foo')">
              Set foo
          </button>
          <button ng-click="$ctrl.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue('bar')">
              Set bar
          </button>
       </div>`,
    controller: function ctrl() {}
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="foobar">
    <my-directive ng-model="foobar"></my-directive>
</form>
```

By instantiating and using the [ng-model controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), the directive will automatically set the form controls as necessary.

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/mdeveSBXf0aojDZI6acZ?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('myModule', [])
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: { ngModelCtrl: 'ngModel' },
    scope: {
      ngModel: '<'
    },
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    template: 
       `<div>
          <button ng-click="$ctrl.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue('foo')">
              Set foo
          </button>
          <button ng-click="$ctrl.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue('bar')">
              Set bar
          </button>
       </div>`,
    controller: function ctrl() {}
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="myModule">
    <h2>ngModel DEMO</h2>
    <form name="myForm">
        <input type="text" ng-model="foobar">
        <my-directive ng-model="foobar"></my-directive>
    </form>
    <br>myForm.$dirty = {{myForm.$dirty}}
    <br>myForm.$pristine = {{myForm.$pristine}}
    <br><button ng-click="myForm.$setDirty()">Set dirty</button>
    <br><button ng-click="myForm.$setPristine()">Set pristine</button>
  </body>
```

I recommend isolate scope with `ngModel` as an input. Output should be done with the [$setViewValue method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)

Comment: I am building a directive, and was hoping to avoid code repetition.

Comment: Worked out really nice. The missing piece of information for me was `bindToController` syntax, since all examples point to link function as a way to use other controllers. Also, `scope: { ngModel: '<' }` did come in handy ;)