# ng-model value does not get updated on ngModelCtrl.$commitViewValue();

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, frontend

I have a directive where I have a template and I am trying to update the ng-model when a user clicks enter. I am able to catch the event and trying to update the value. I have a watcher on the element in a controller but the watcher function never gets triggered after commitViewValue

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('aa')
        .directive('ss', [
            function() {

                return {
                    restrict: 'EA',
                    replace: true,
                    transclude: true,
                    scope: {
                        placeholder: '@'
                    },
                    require: 'ngModel',
                    template: '<div class="clear">' +

                        '<input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" ng-model-options="{updateOn:\'change blur\'}" />' +
                        '</div>',

                link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                    elem.bind("keyup",function(e) {
                        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                            ngModelCtrl.$commitViewValue();
                            scope.$apply(ngModelCtrl.$setTouched);
                        }
                    });
                }

                }
            }
        ]);
})();


 $scope.$watch('pr', function(newValue,oldValue){
                console.log('val>>' + newValue);
            });
```

```html
<ss ng-model="pr"></ss>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$setViewValue` to move the data from the isolate scope to the parent scope:

```
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        elem.bind("keyup",function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                 ̶n̶g̶M̶o̶d̶e̶l̶C̶t̶r̶l̶.̶$̶c̶o̶m̶m̶i̶t̶V̶i̶e̶w̶V̶a̶l̶u̶e̶(̶)̶;̶
                //USE $setViewValue
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.ngModel);
                //scope.$apply(ngModelCtrl.$setTouched);
            }
        });
```

Also use one-way `<` binding if you want the parent controller able to set the model.

```
scope: {ngModel: '<'}
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/i794SNlxCK0z7ExcVpJk?p=preview)

For more information, see

- [StackOverflow - Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875989/angular-custom-form-component-directive-and-dirty-property/44878104#44878104)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Works perfectly.