# How to dynamically add ng-model name to template added dinamically with ng-repeat and button click?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-template

I have a template app/views/templates/destForm.tpl.html

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Departure</label>
         <input class="form-control form-control-rounded input-lg" type="text" ng-model="???????" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I include it in my html page like this:

```
<form action="" name="formPackages">
    <div ng-repeat="form in destForms track by $index">
        <dest-form></dest-form>
    </div>
...
```

In my controller I've got this code:

```
$scope.destForms = [];
$scope.addForm = function(){
    var formIndex = $scope.destForms.length + 1;
    $scope.destForms.push('app/views/templates/destForm.tpl.html');
}

$scope.addForm();
```

**EDIT 1:** (suggested in comments)

This is my directive.

```
function destForm () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
          ngModel: '<'
        },
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: '$quoteAskCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/templates/destForm.tpl.html',
        controller: 'quoteAskCtrl'
    };
}
```

**EDIT 2**
How can I set ng-model within the template html to be available within the $scope of my controller? User may have the option to make just one departure or several, that's what I add dynamically with

**EDIT 3**
This is what I'm trying to reach, so when form submitted, I need to loop within this departure-destinations to post them to my DB.

[image: screenshot]

I'm trying to add a template for each "departure" the user has to make.
How to add ng-model dynamically so I can collect data in my controler to  make an $http.post?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be wiser to use a component instead of `ng-include`. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Understanding Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). Also [Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44878104/5535245).

Comment: I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Ok. I created a directive to add the template as a component. I'll edit the question. How to SET ng-model inside the template html to be available in $scope's controller? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your directive:

```
<input class="form-control form-control-rounded input-lg" type="text" ng-model="$quoteAskCtrl.ngModel" />
```

and your html:

```
<form action="" name="formPackages">
   <div ng-repeat="form in destForms track by $index">
   <dest-form ng-model="form"></dest-form>
</div>
```

explanation:
Your directive expects to receive propety as 'ngModel' from the parent object.

Because you have set:`controllerAs: '$quoteAskCtrl',`
You need to access it this way:`ng-model="$quoteAskCtrl.ngModel"`

Comment: Oh. I think this is it. I'll try and let you know. Thanks.